# qtbindings ubuntu install error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, qtruby

I try install [qtbindings](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings) gem on my new virtual machine. I did everything according to the instructions on gem page, but something is wrong. I have installation errors:

```
vagrant@machine:~$ sudo gem install qtbindings
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qtbindings:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb

make
mkdir ext/build
mkdir bin/1.9
mkdir bin/plugins
mkdir bin/plugins/accessible
mkdir bin/plugins/bearer
mkdir bin/plugins/codecs
mkdir bin/plugins/designer
mkdir bin/plugins/graphicssystems
mkdir bin/plugins/iconengines
mkdir bin/plugins/imageformats
mkdir bin/plugins/phonon_backend
mkdir bin/plugins/qmltooling
mkdir bin/plugins/sqldrivers
mkdir lib/1.9
cd ext/build; rm -rf CMakeFiles
cd ext/build; rm -rf generator
cd ext/build; rm -rf smoke
cd ext/build; rm -rf ruby
cd ext/build; rm *
rm: cannot remove '*': No such file or directory
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)
cd ext/build; \
cmake -DCMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED_VERSION=2.6 \
-G "Unix Makefiles" \
-Wno-dev \
-DRUBY_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 \
..
/bin/sh: 2: cmake: not found
make: [build] Error 127 (ignored)
cd ext/build; make
make[1]: Entering directory `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.3/ext/build'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.3/ext/build'
make: *** [build] Error 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.3/./gem_make.out
```

OS Ubunu 16.04. What i did wrong?

**SOLVED**

install cmake and qt-sdk

Thanks [ajinkya-pisal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302651/ajinkya-pisal)

Comment: I believe that instructions on the qtbindings github are prettry straightforward.
`On linux/MacOSX you must make sure you have all the necessary prerequisites installed or the compile will fail.`

Also, error logs points that `cmake: not found`. Can you try installing `cmake` first and run `gem install qtbindings`? let me know if that fixex the issue or not

Comment: Thanks for help. Install cmake, then install qt-sdk. It solved my problem. It was possible to install a smaller number of packages than qt-sdk  with all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Of note, if you use multiple Ruby versions via RVM, you need to make sure you have 2.2.6 installed and selected. To check which versions you have installed, run

```
rvm list
```

If you do not have Ruby 2.2.6 installed, you will need to install it by running

```
rvm install 2.2.6
```

To select 2.2.6, run

```
rvm use 2.2.6
```

If it's a new installation, you'll also need to add 2.2.6 gems to your PATH. Do this by running

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```